# Add text with carousal pro

Tags: android, flutter, slider

I was wondering if there was any way to include a title or text within carousal pro widget in flutter? A text that changes when the carousal changes too?

Comment: Please add a little more information about what yo want to do, but if you only want to add a text and the plugin does no allowed you could add every image in a stack and when you are creating it put the title where you want it with a Positioned Widget inside the stack. If could help more if you provide more info about what you are doing.

Comment: So basically what i have in my carousal slider is about 4 different games in each slide. What i want to do is to display the title of each game on the slide. For example, if the image is a cover of the game days gone. I want a text displaying the name of the game.